# reordering sorted array to level-order array without queue

Tags: array, binary-tree

I have very large sorted array, stored on the disk.
I can random access any element.

I want to make it level-ordered in order to speed up binary search there. The idea is borrowed from:

http://bannalia.blogspot.bg/2015/06/cache-friendly-binary-search.html

If I do this way, I believe I will be able to utilize the disk cache much better.

However I do not see easy way to create level-ordered without using queue. Because the data is immutable, I do not need fast solution.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: In what sense do you want to avoid using a stack? You don't have enough RAM to contain log(length of the array) values, as the building / traversal of a tree requires? If so, how reordering elements will help you? You won't have enough RAM to cache the hot elements anyway. If you have a decent amount of RAM, you can consider creating a tree on the fly, without storing it whole, by a bottom-up approach (see e.g. http://articles.leetcode.com/convert-sorted-list-to-balanced-binary/)

Comment: sorry, is not stack but queue. Yes, I don't have ram to load whole "level" into the queue.

Comment: What kind of speed-up are you expecting from the reordering then? I assume it's putting the hottest nodes together so that reading them hits the file cache more often because they share the same blocks. This makes sense for a certain initial portion of most-hit blocks, but not the rest. So if you can build a few top levels of the tree but leave the rest untouched, it could help performance somehow without spending inordinate time on reordering. OTOH if you lack RAM, you can extend your paging file and do a full reorder; while slow, it must be faster and simpler than juggling temporary files.

Comment: Also, you can run the algorithm basically unchanged by allocating a file of the same size, and use `seek()` to write elements in it as if it were a RAM array. It's not very fast, but the OS's file cache should reasonably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder can be done in "lame" way, e.g. print out level by level.

I was unable to remove the recursion, but it does not need a queue.

Also because we are working with an array, we do not need to touch it more that N times - e.g. we touch every element only once.

Here are conceptual implementation that list only first few levels, but the idea is clear.

Implementation in C++, but C would be almost the similar.

```
#include <cstdio>

void reorder(size_t const start, size_t const end, size_t const level, size_t const clevel = 0){
    if (start >= end){
        printf("NULL\n");
        return;
    }

    size_t const mid = start + ((end - start) >> 1);

    if (clevel == level){
        // here we touch the array
        printf("%zu\n", mid);
        return;
    }

    reorder(start,   mid, level, clevel + 1);
    reorder(mid + 1, end, level, clevel + 1);
}

void reorder(size_t const size, size_t const maxLevels){
    for(size_t level = 0; level < maxLevels; ++level)
        reorder(0, size, level);
}

int main(){
    reorder(20, 4);
}
```

Here is additional example:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5890330f69402c2ef637055070a5ad2